# ResultSet concurrency 1008 is not supported

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to fetch a row from table and update few columns. While trying to update the resultset I am getting below exception. Please guide what is wrong here.

```
    Java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Resultset concurrency 1008 is not supported
```

I am using snowflake-jdbc-3.13.8.jar

```
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.StringWriter;
    import java.sql.*;
    import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.*;

   public class SampleUnwrap {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String user = "<user>";
            String password = "<pass>";
            String account = "<account>";
            String JDBC_DRIVER = "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver";
            String warehouse = "<wh>";
            String role = "<role>";
            String db = "<db>";
            String schema = "PUBLIC";
            String queryString = "SSL=on&tracing=ALL&database=" + db + "&role=" + role +  "&warehouse=" + warehouse;
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:snowflake" + "://" + account + ".snowflakecomputing.com" + "/?" + queryString;
            Connection conn1;

            try {
                    conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, user, password);
              PreparedStatement stmt = conn1.prepareStatement("select a,b from TEST where c =?", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
              stmt.setString(1, "Value1");

              ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(resultSet.next()){

  
       resultSet.updateString("d","test")
        resultSet.updateRow();

    }      
    
                    conn1.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                
            }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest dropping `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` which says the result set can be altered after pulling it down. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-concur-updatable-resultset-in-jdbc-explain

Answer (score 0):

according to notes on [this page](https://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/11/jdbc-what-is-resultset-in-java-types.html)

> getConcurrency() - method returns concurrency mode of this ResultSet object. It may be CONCUR_READ_ONLY (1007) or CONCUR_UPDATABLE  (1008)

it implies your selection of `CONCUR_UPDATABLE` is not supported.

This [page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-concur-updatable-resultset-in-jdbc-explain) suggests that feature allows you to alter the result set you get back from the database, and thus if you don't use that ability, maybe you should not ask for it. And if you need it, it seems you cannot have it.

Comment: Yes it seems CONCUR_UPDATABLE is not supported. Then how I can achieve it? I need to update only few columns in the current row.

Comment: @Nid but what does it "mean to update a value in the current row" inside your Java code, because the the result set is also read by yet more Java code, and that want to see "clean data". You do you plan to send the data set back to the DB to alter the tables. Because I suspect the latter is not supported. because there is no way to refer to rows if they do not have a distinct key/values. If you are wanting to alter the data in Snowflake, I would build up an UPATE command and do it that way.

Comment: For UPDATE I will build command and do. But what to be done if I need to insert the same record with few column values updated. There are around 100 columns, I am fetching it in resultset and then update only those few columns and need to Insert a new row with all other column values same as previous one. There also I guess resultSet.insertRow() is not supported.